# Need help in Regex Replace C#

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a way that the Regex will check the first and the last character, but will replace only the `IV` and not the spaces.

```
Regex.Replace("This is IV item.", "[^A-Za-z0-9](IV)[^A-Za-z0-9]", "fourth");
```

Please don't tell me about MatchEvaluator and other Match based things, I need a one line solution, and one line doesn't mean combining code, it means using Replace method only.

Also I am not talking only about spaces, I am talking in general for any character, like: `(`

Once again, let me clear, I am not looking for anything other than some regex symbols that will match the characters but won't replace it and not this method:

```
Regex.Replace("This is IV item.", "([^A-Za-z0-9])(IV)([^A-Za-z0-9])", "$1fourth$3");
```

as this regex are parameters to some code that will automatically automatically uses $1 for some thing and I don't want to change that code, so is there a way so that $1 will be `IV` only, while checking that the previous character also.

Comment: If I may be so forward as to ask, why do you need a one-liner for this?

Comment: as already told the Regex Replace is in some other lib, which I don't want to modify. the Regex is input to that. So the question is about writing regex and not C# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question exactly what you want to accept and reject, but I think you need something like this:

```
Regex.Replace("This is IV item.", "(?<=[^A-Za-z0-9])(IV)(?=[^A-Za-z0-9])", "fourth");
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Regex.Replace("This is IV item.", @"\bIV\b", "fourth");
```

Comment: what about "This is !IV item." I said it can be any symbol.

Comment: This works for "This is !IV item." It fails for "This is \_IV\_ item though."

Comment: The word boundary (\b) method is very simple and often all you need. If this isn't enough then you should use the look-behind/look-ahead solutions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are so called **look behinds** and **look aheads**.
Try using `(?<=\ )IV(?!<=\ )` as a pattern.

Comment: +1 as is the what I was looking. Sorry, not accepting this cause I run into issues with the syntax given, so accepting the one with the example.

Comment: I think you meant `(?<=\ )IV(?=\ )`. Anyway, the OP said the surrounding characters could be anything other than ASCII letters and digits, not just spaces.